# How to make a new controller default controller in asp.net core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

So, I am new in asp.net core, and I am trying to create a new web api in asp.net core. The default controller is Weatherforecast, in other words when I debug the application in the browser the main page is always Weatherforecast. I added a new controller named MainController.cs, and I wrote some simple code there:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MainController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string getmain()
    {
        return "welcome";
    }

    
}
```

}
in a word, i want my application's main controller to be https://localhost:43372/main and not https://localhost:43372/weatherforecast, also I tried to delete Weatherforecast controller and Weatherforecast.cs file, however when I deleted it, the main page was still https://localhost:43372/weatherforecast, but with error because I deleted the files. So, how can i make my new controller default for me web app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to modify launchUrl in the **launchSettings.json** file that exists in the properties folder.

**"launchUrl": "weatherforecast"** **-> "launchUrl": "main"**

Please make sure that the main is a valid controller.

Comment: @givexa Once any response solves your problem, please accept it as answer so that it adds to the reputation of the person who helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a little look at ***Properties/launchSettings.json***.

If you want to create a new controller,
***Controller / Right Click / Add / Controller.***

Comment: oh thanks it worked! I just had to change launchurl's from weatherforecast to main in Properties/launchSettings.json....

Comment: You're welcome,  you can contact me when you have problems :)

Answer (score 1):

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Main}/{action=getmain}/{id?}");
 });
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not the most helpful, even though they might answer the question. Please explain in a few lines how this answers the question.

Comment: Upvoted as this is a better fix. Updating the launch settings is ok, but the endpoint in the Startup.cs file ill still be pointing to WeatherForecast.  code only answers aren't too helpful, but the question was quite straight forward. IMO